# How to display new records on screen without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have to display the all the records on the screen which are inserted into the database without refreshing the page. I have 3 columns called as Firstname, Lastname, Email and after clicking on the submit button data are inserting in the database using ajax Which is working.

Now I am fetching the records on the same screen without refresh the page but it is not working when I am refreshing the page then it is displaying the last record which is inserted.

Please check below link. You will get an idea what I am asking. Inserted data and display data at the same time.

http://prntscr.com/g953bs

**Index.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include('../../db/connection.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" id="register" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Lastname">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
<table border="1" style="margin-top: 25px;">
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
 <?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                <td>".$row['fname']."</td>
                <td>".$row['lname']."</td> 
                <td>".$row['email']."</td>
            </tr>";

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
 ?>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#register').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission

            var fname = $("#fname").val();
            var lname = $("#lname").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var dataString = 'fname='+ fname + '&lname='+ lname + '&email='+ email;
            $.ajax(
            {
                url:'process.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:dataString,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    // $("#table-container").html(data);
                    $("#register")[0].reset();
                },
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Process.php**

```
$firstname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lastname=$_POST['lname'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (fname, lname, email) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: You are showing data fetched and stored in $result. While submitting form by ajax you are not refreshing the page. So $result is storing the previous data only.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#IdTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>id<td>fname<td>lname<td>email</tr>');
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, But where should I use it?

Comment: inside of success

Comment: I tried your code, Records are inserting in the database but it is displaying on screen after refreshing the page

Comment: Yes, It is working. There was the same issue from my end.

Comment: But the id is auto incremented that is not displaying. Can you help me in this?

Comment: To show it i think you can use this mysqli_insert_id($conn)Like this  $('#IdTable tr:last').after('<tr><td><?php echo mysqli_insert_id($conn);?> 
 <td>fname<td>lname<td>email</tr>');

Comment: $('table tr:last').after('<tr><td><?php echo mysqli_insert_id($conn);?> </td><td>' +fname +'</td><td>'+lname+'</td><td>'+email+'</td></tr>');

Answer (score 0):

Define id to the table

```
<table border="1" style="margin-top: 25px;" id="myTable">
```

Changes in ajax call

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url:'process.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:dataString,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>' +fname +'</td><td>'+lname+'</td><td>'+email+'</td></tr>');
                    $("#register")[0].reset();
                },
            });
```

Note: Also you should handle the case if eror while inserting in your code  as currently you are only taking positive case.

I hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for replying Naincy, I tried but its not working

Comment: I tried your code, Records are inserting in the database but it is displaying on screen after refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd like to suggest taking a look at [binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) with mysqli to make your query saver.

Then in order to add the date without refreshing you could return the data on successful insert. Then [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) this data to the table.

Example Process.php

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".mysqli_insert_id($conn)."</td>
            <td>".$firstname."</td>
            <td>".$lastname."</td> 
            <td>".$email."</td>
        </tr>";
} else {
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have only one table then use below code.

```
 $('table tr:last').after('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

If you have any class or id then you can modify below syntax as $('selector tr:last')

**Use it in success of ajax call**